# Unable to join ISE to Active Directory

Tags: cisco-ise

I'm unable to join ISE to the Windows domain. I tried using an admin account that I login to ISE. The first error stated that the username and password was incorrect.  So I created an admin account in AD, and made it a domain admin.  Now when I attempt to join it to the domain in ISE, I get a new error stating 'Failed to find domain controller in domain, there is no available DC's'. This is in the detailed logs, but the name of the error is LW_ERROR_CLOCK_SKEW. Error code 40087

I can ping the domain controller from ISE, and I can ping ISE from the domain controller.  The time is synced correctly between ISE and the NTP source, which is the core switch.

Comment: What's the ISE's DNS setup? DNS is required to find a DC.

Comment: I have the ip name-server defined in the ISE config.  And I have a Host A record configured for ISE, along with a PTR.

Comment: DNS needs to point to Windows DNS, complete with DC records. Additionally, the LW_ERROR_CLOCK_SKEW might indicate asynchronous time between ISE and DC - I suspect that an offset larger than x prevents login. Take a look at the timezones as well.

Comment: Correct Zac67, but as I stated in my post I've already covered those bases and verified.  DNS does indeed point to Windows DNS, all DC records exist accordingly, and the time and timezone are correct.  The time is literally about 3 seconds off.

Comment: 3 seconds?  If they're synced they should be the same.

Comment: Yes, this could be the issue as I was syncing them manually.   I have the NTP server configured in ISE, which is the core switch.  But ISE won't sync with it automatically.  What would cause that to not sync?  I can ping the NTP source just fine. Do you think that 3 seconds though would cause the issue?

Comment: Regardless, I went ahead and changed the NTP server to the DC across the board, and the time is now synced up to the second.  Yet, I'm still getting a clock skew error when attempting to join ISE to the domain. Even though I can ping the DC, ISE keeps saying it can't find any domain controllers.

Comment: The issue is definitely with ISE.  I logged into the ISE console today, did a 'sh clock' and it says Sun Sep 10 23:31:51 PDT 2017.  So ISE is not syncing correctly with the NTP, which is now the DC itself.  Short of me configuring the ntp server in ISE, how else am I suppose to make them sync accordingly?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your ISE server's clock is not synchronized with the Active Directory DC, then authentication can fail.  This is because AD is using Kerberos auth with timestamped tickets.  You've stated your ISE is synched with the core switch, but what does the DC also sync with that NTP source?

Also, you mention you gave Domain Admin privileges to the service account you created.  This is likely way too high a privilege level for this account. You should reference the ISE documentation for the needed permissions.  But from my experience a standard user account should suffice.

[ISE 2.0 AD Integration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/ise/2-0/ise_active_directory_integration/b_ISE_AD_integration_20.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I agree it's way to high and we'll pull that back.  That was just for testing purposes. The DC is also using the same NTP source.